# Thunderbolt to VGA

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm buying a new MacBook Pro tomorrow, but I'm unsure on which adapter to buy for a VGA adapter. Is it the [Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MB572Z/A?fnode=MTY1NDA5OQ)? The MacBook Pro doesn't say it has a Mini DisplayPort, only Thunderbolt. So am I going to buy the correct one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Thunderbolt **is** Mini DisplayPort for all purposes. (Note: not all *practical* purposes, *all* purposes.) Technically, Thunderbolt is PCI Express and DisplayPort multiplexed, the upshot being that every Thunderbolt port is a MDP port and can be used exactly the same as a normal Mini DisplayPort port. This fact is unchanged as you travel down the daisy-chain of Thunderbolt devices (assuming you have any).